# How to remove one side of the axes label in scatterplot matrix (splom in R)?

Tags: r, lattice

I have created a scatterplot matrix using splom in R but the reviewer is not happy with having the axes label on both sides in each of the matrix. Anyone know how to get axis label only on one side? Here is a my R code below:

```
print(splom(~d[11:16], 
        groups = paste(Trt), data = d, pch=c(0:3), col=1, cex=0.7,  
         axis.text.cex=0.6, axis.line.tck=0.1,
         points = list(pch = 0:3, cex = 1.2, col = 1)))
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by providing the necessary package and a [sample of data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: How does the reviewer want you to handle the expected collisions at the corners?